# Is every manifold a double coset space?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups

Given any manifold $ M $ does there exist  $ G $ a Lie group and $ H,\Gamma $ closed subgroups of $ G $ such that 
$$
M \cong \Gamma \backslash G/H
$$

I was inspired to ask by this question:  [Example of a manifold which is not a homogeneous space of any Lie group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89345/example-of-a-manifold-which-is-not-a-homogeneous-space-of-any-lie-group)

Comment: The question as currently stated ($\Gamma$ is not assumed to lie in $G$) doesn't match the title.

Comment: @Ycor Ok you are right. I edited the question so it aligns with the title. I expect the answer now to be "no". The question I'm more interested in is if $ \Gamma $ is not necessarily a subgroup. In particular I'm curious if there is a general enough structure such that every manifold "come from a lie group/ comes from a homogeneous space" using only algebraic data (e.g. quotienting by group actions).  Although I should probably just ask that in a different question with a different title.

Comment: Similarly I'd be interested in a large class of manifolds all of which come from homogeneous spaces by quotienting out by a group action. I'd be interested in results of the sort "manifolds with X geometric structure always arise as the quotient by a free and proper action of their fundamental group on their universal cover and their universal cover is always homogeneous." Again I should probably make another question.

Comment: The fact that all surfaces arise this way should be noted.

Comment: The question still doesn’t match the title. ([Double coset space](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_coset) entails a specific way for $\Gamma$ to act on $G/H$.)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler I understand the current question with this specific way (although I'd have denoted $\Gamma\backslash G/H$)

Comment: @YCor Well, biquotients appear to have had [several](//arxiv.org/abs/math/0210231) [definitions](//arxiv.org/abs/math/0210247), and then the OP seems to want “a bit more general”. (How exactly?)

Comment: @Will Sawin I know all surfaces (both orientable and non orientable) arise this way, that’s part of why I asked the question. Is it true for all connected 2 manifolds (not necessarily compact)?

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler The commit about “a bit more general” is leftover from before the first edit when the question was more general. I’ve deleted it. Now everything should match the title.

Comment: it is true for all 2-manifolds, (I think this requires assuming that your definition of manifold requires second countability) in the sense that noncompact 2-manifolds with nontrivial fundamental group can be shown to have the hyperbolic plane as their universal cover.

Comment: I can't speak for Kapovich but my assumptions would lead me to think he is referring to the type of double-quotient construction used to make geometric manifolds.

Comment: I have a vague recollection that the answer is negative, and that this is an old theorem of Wu-Chung Hsiang's.  I believe he shows exotic spheres are not of this form.

Comment: I'd be curious about the connected sum of two (or more) copies of $S^1\times S^2$ (or 3-tori).