# How special are homogeneous spaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, homogeneous-spaces

Let $M$ be a smooth finite dimensional manifold, how restrictive is it to require $M$ to admit a smooth action by a finite dimensional Lie group $G$?

Related questions/approaches: Of course we need $\mathrm{dim}(G) \geq \mathrm{dim}(M)$, are there any results relating the minimal dimension of a Lie group acting transitively to that of $M$, perhaps in special cases?

Going in the other direction, any criteria which easily allow to say that a given smooth manifold does not admit a transitive group action?

EDIT: in the first question I meant to write *transitive* smooth group action.

Comment: In the first question, you have to specify what sort of action you want. Besides the trivial action, every manifold admits vector fields and hence non-trivial $\mathbb{R}$ actions.

Comment: The answer is "extremely special".  There are plenty of restrictions on these manifolds.  Take a look at the $2$ and $3$ dimensional cases, for example.  But there is a long history to this question, going back to the 60's.

Answer (score 10):

I suppose you want the action to be transitive as your title suggests. In this case, a classical theorem of Mostow (in 1950 for surfaces, in 2005 in general) says that for a compact homogeneous space $M = G/H$ the Euler characteristics is non-negative.

Mostow, G.D.: The extensibility of local Lie groups of transformations and groups on surfaces. Ann.
Math. (2) 52, 606–636 (1950)

Mostow, G.D.: A structure theorem for homogeneous spaces. Geom. Dedic. 114, 87–102 (2005)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89345/example-of-a-manifold-which-is-not-a-homogeneous-space-of-any-lie-group?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant to ask for transitive action, I have now edited the question.